# Wordpress: Query child pages with specific templates for each page

Tags: wordpress, parent-child

I created a query to call all child pages of the current parent page. This works great, however each child page has a custom template. I don't know how to add a custom query parameter to account for the template. Currently I query the_content for each child page, however that doesn't account for the template.

Can anyone help me modify the query?

```
<?php $children = get_pages( 
    array(
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
        'sort_order' => 'ASC',
        'hierarchical' => 0,
        'parent' => $post->ID,
        'post_type' => 'projects',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_wp_page_template',
                'value' => 'template-city.php', // template name as stored in the dB
            )
        )
    ));

foreach( $children as $post ) { 
        setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <div class="section-container">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use get_post_meta !

With template_redirect action :

```
function my_page_template_redirect()
{
    global $post;
    if(get_post_type($post) == 'projects' )
    {
         $tpl = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template');
         if ($tpl) {
             include( get_template_directory() . $tpl );
             exit();
         }
    }
}    
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
```

Comment: thanks for your response! Where would that fit into my template?

Comment: I figured it out thanks to you! I modified your code: <?php $tpl = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_post_template', true);
     include(  $tpl ); ?>

Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: I'm really late, but nowadays the codex recommends using the `template_redirect` hook for this http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include

Answer (score 1):

I think `get_pages` function doesn't use `meta_query`, you need to do something like this:

```
$children = get_pages( 
    array(
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
        'sort_order' => 'ASC',
        'hierarchical' => 0,
        'parent' => $post->ID,
        'post_type' => 'projects',
        'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
        'meta_value' => 'template-city.php',
    ));
```

Or use `get_posts` function that uses `meta_query`.